# Send data from one devtool to the other

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I have 2 separate browser windows each with there own devtool running.
Is it possible to send data from one devtool to the other? I don't see anything in mentioned on the chrome devtool exented docs about this

Comment: What do you mean by data?

Comment: Just any data, object string whatever. At this point not so important

Comment: I think we still don't understand what data is? Submit a form, post, get? You want to send div, button?

Comment: Whatver gets the job done

Comment: Can you do a post to send data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how much data and what type of data you want to write/read, but maybe you get use of `window.localStorage` to write in one window and read into the other window.

Comment: localStorage is available in multiple sessions, but I'm now sure if it suits your needs. You might also give it a try to Electron.js platform, and see if it offers what you need. As long as we don't know what is your purpose, it is hard to give a proper solution.

Comment: I just need to have a string of data appear in the other devtool . Local storage might be exactly what I need.

Comment: I actually worked with local storage many times but totally forgot about it later on

Answer (score 4):

Edit - Directly there is no way(apart from storage event handler) to send data across one dev tool tab to another.

But by means of Chrome Extension it can be done.

1) Content js would send data from one tab to background js

2) Background Js would then send the data to another tab, of which you should know the tabId

3) Receiving tab would receive the data from background.

I know this way to get your work done, and if you get to know some other way as well. Do share.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to look into this

Comment: Good alternative, but takes bit more time as compared to local storage method but also it's kindda tool you can used to such tasks.